# Installing mysql client 5.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, mysql, official-repositories

I am trying to install mysql 5.6 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I understand that the packages available for mysql are with version 5.7 but in order to install 5.6 I did the following steps

```
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade --fix-missing -y
RUN apt-get clean 
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
RUN apt install mysql-client-5.6 -y
```

This still gives the following error

```
137958 [INFO] Package mysql-client-5.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mysql-testsuite-5.7 mariadb-server-core-10.0 mariadb-client-10.0
  mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-5.7
137963 [INFO] [91mE: Package 'mysql-client-5.6' has no installation candidate
```

What is the correct repository to install from?

Comment: Is this by chance being done on docker?

Comment: Yes it is, do you see issues with that?

Comment: Every invocation of RUN is making a new image layer, it might be more efficient to run all the command in a single RUN command, as is more typical. See here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

Comment: Yes, do you think that causes issues with the mysql installation?

Comment: As for the correct repository to install from: the one meant for the OS version is the correct one. If you really to need mysql-client 5.6, either use 14.04 as a base or you might be able to download the deb package file and install it directly. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: At no point are the 16.04 repositories removed from `/etc/apt/sources` or the package index updated after adding the trusty repository. That's 2 reasons it's not going to see the 5.6 version.